# Generate random numbers from a three dimensional probability distribution

Tags: distribution, probability

How can I generate random numbers from a given three- dimensional PDF? The Probability Distribution Function gives the probability of a particle having any given set of cooridinetes in 3D space.

I have defined the function for the PDF, and I can evaluate it at discrete intervals, but I do not know where to go from there. I would use the method of inverse transform sampling, but since the PDF is 3D, I do not know if I can calculate the discrete cumulative distribution function. Is it possible to do this using another method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your spatial coordinate system is discrete, treat it as a univariate generation problem to generate triplets.

If you're talking about a continuous distribution you probably want to use conditional probability.  In principle you should be able to derive the marginal distribution of the X's, the conditional distribution of Y given X, and the conditional distribution of Z given X & Y.  Then generate X, Y, and Z sequentially from their marginal and conditional distributions.

In practice this may be quite challenging.

Addendum

Perhaps the easiest scheme would be to generate a multidimensional normal vector of length 3.  This would give the highest density near the origin and taper off symmetrically in all directions.  You could displace it with a mean vector if the density is highest at some other location, you could scale the dimensions independently with different variances, or you could induce arbitrary axis alignments by specifying a variance/covariance matrix to get correlated normals.

Comment: "If your spatial coordinate system is discrete, treat it as a univariate generation problem to generate triplets."
-Can you be more specific? How would I do this?
The distribution is continuous, but I could discretize the distribution by evaluating it at regular intervals.

Comment: You could specify a bounded grid of possible locations and their associated probabilities.  If you had a 11x11x11 grid you specify 1000 probabilities to generate (i,j,k) for -5<=i,j,k<=5.  You can see that the table grows very quickly.  If there is some nice symmetry to how likely things are, you can use a coarse grid to get to an area, and then select a location within that area using one or more successively finer grids.

Comment: I still do not understand how your answer relates to my question. I want to generate a set of random points according to a multivariate probability density function (either discrete or continuous).

Comment: It's hard to talk in more than generalities without knowing more about your multivariate density.  Does it have special properties that can be leveraged, such as symmetry?  Without more details, it's hard to say more than "generate X from the marginal f(x), Y from the conditional f(y|x), and Z from the conditional f(z|x & y)".  If you don't have a specific joint density, then the multivariate normal is pretty easy. If you have a specific alternate density in mind and want more than general guidance, you need to tell us your particulars.

Comment: @pjs what about a table `x1 y1 z1 p1  , x2 y2 z2 p2 ` etc?

Comment: @AlexanderCska What about it? That’s specifically addressed in my comment of Jul-17, 2013 at 1339.

Comment: I found a way how to do it, basically it works in the same way how 1d histograms are sampled. Your answer is a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Feel free to post your own answer. That's how things work here.

Answer (score 0):

If can tolerate discretising your three dimensions then you can do this by generating a cumulative distribution for your 3D distribution in a similar way to how you would do this for a 1D distribution. Let me explain:

In 1D you take p(x) and discretise to get p<sub>i</sub> = p(x<sub>i</sub>) over x. You can think of p<sub>i</sub> as like a histogram that represents your probability distribution. The p<sub>i</sub> are integrals of p(x) over the range of x represented by x<sub>i</sub>, which will have some width. The cumulative distribution, C(x<sub>i</sub>), is then just the sum of the p<sub>i</sub> up to x<sub>i</sub> and will be some 'S' shaped monotonic function with a range between 0 and 1. You then draw uniform-random numbers between 0 and 1 corresponding to C<sub>i</sub> and see to which x<sub>i</sub> value these map.

A 2D example will suffice to see how the above generalises to more than 1D: Imagine a normalised p(x,y) that you could discretise to p(x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>j</sub>). You can then sum this so that you have C<sub>i,j</sub> = C(x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>j</sub>). You just have to make a choice whether to first go along 'x<sub>i</sub>' or 'y<sub>j</sub>' when doing your integration. Either you snake along like C<sub>1,1</sub>, C<sub>2,1</sub>, ..., C<sub>n,1</sub>, C<sub>1,2</sub>, ... or with the indices flipped. In either case, the result will be a C<sub>i,j</sub> array of unique values between 0 and 1. You can then pick a uniform-random number between 0 and 1 corresponding to C<sub>i,j</sub>, which then maps to a unique x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>j</sub> coordinate pair. This gives you a random number from the discrete probability distribution and automatically takes care of all correlations that exist between x and y.

You can make your coordinate-discretisation very fine if you need to, but this becomes costly as you increase the number of dimensions you are sampling from (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).